# Laravel blade display data with chunk in differents windows size

Tags: php, laravel, size

I show the data grouped in threes, and what I want is that if the size of the browser window is less than x, I will show them in pairs. How can I do it?

```
@foreach ($data['news']->chunk(3) as $chunk)
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 pad_bottom_2">

    @foreach($chunk as $key => $new)
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 pad_right_1">
            <article>
                // CODE
            </article>
        </div>
    @endforeach

</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to handle is with CSS.

```
.col-xs-12 {Your normal styles}
...

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) { /* in case x = 700 */
    .col-x-12 {another style to match what you want for small screen}
    ...
}
```

Another way is to do it with javascript/jquery. Anyway this is the duty of client side codes and is not related to Laravel.

Read [This intro](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp), and you may google **Responsive Web Design** for further reading.